MAUI Hybrid page hang
I have a MAUI app that seems to hang when running on a device delivered through test flight, but works perfectly fine in the simulator.
It is a MAUI Hybrid using Blazor to open a page. It loads the page, starts a loading spinner, retrives some data and updates the view and closes the spinner.
But the view doesn't update and the spinner doesn't stop.
I have added some simple logging in Sentry to check it is executing all the code and it does.
I know the spinner works as I use it in other pages.
No hidden crashes in Sentry that I can see.
I've got no idea how to even get more information about this issue! Any advice?
OnAfterRenderAsync Method
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Started page load");
            Matches = DashboardAPI.GetMyCompetitionMatches().Result;

            SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Retrieved matches");

            if(Matches.Count() == 0)
            {
                SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Matches found: 0");
                _spinnerService.Hide(); 
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                Leagues = Matches
                    .Select(i => new League {
                        LeagueName = i.LeagueName,
                        AvatarFileName = i.LeagueAvatarFileName,
                        CustomDomain = i.LeagueCustomDomain,
                        Id = i.LeagueId,
                        Path = i.LeaguePath
                    })
                    .DistinctBy(i => i.LeagueName)
                    .ToList();

                SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Got the leagues");

                BookableVenues = new List<BookableVenue>();
                foreach(var league in Leagues)
                {
                    var venues = DashboardAPI.GetBookableVenues(league.Id).Result;
                    BookableVenues.AddRange(venues);
                }
            }

            SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Finoshed page load about to trigger state change");
            _spinnerService.Hide();  
            //StateHasChanged();
            SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Hidden spinner");
        }       
        _spinnerService.Hide();            
    } 

Project File

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
            The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
            When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
            The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
            either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>RackEmAppMobile</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>RackEmApp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.rackemapp.mobileapp</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.4.7</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>77</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
        <UseInterpreter>-all</UseInterpreter> 
        <MtouchUseLlvm>True</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <AotAssemblies>False</AotAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="beep.mp3" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="blazored.modal" Version="7.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="blazored.toast" Version="4.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="blazorspinner" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="communitytoolkit.maui" Version="9.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="currietechnologies.razor.sweetalert2" Version="5.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.92" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.92" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="8.0.92" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="mudblazor" Version="7.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="OnScreenSizeMarkup.Maui" Version="3.0.18" />
        <PackageReference Include="plugin.maui.audio" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.CalendarStore" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Radzen.Blazor" Version="5.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="restsharp" Version="112.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sentry.Maui" Version="4.12.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite" Version="3.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
        <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.blazor" Version="27.1.53" />
        <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.blazor.themes" Version="27.1.53" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Views/" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


